# Error al tomar un valor de input y mandarlo a base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

espero y tengan un excelente momento, quería pedirles ayuda para resolver este problema: estoy intentando guardar valores que extraigo de un input en HTML y guardarlo en mi base de datos usando PHP. La cuestiones que al hacerlo me salta los siguientes mensajes de error además de solo guardar 0 en la base:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A continuación procederé a dejar tanto el código del formulario donde ingrese los datos a guardar como del código PHP encargado de ello:

**Codigo de los Input**

```
<form method="POST" action="guardar.php">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Numero de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelNumero" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>CVV</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelcvv" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
   <div class="form-element">
        <label>Nombre de tarjeta</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelnombre" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Fecha de vecimiento</label>
        <input type="text" name="labelfecha" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-element">
        <label>Numero de telefono</label>
        <input type="tex" name="labeltelefono" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required/> 
    </div>                                
    <button type="submit" name="PAGO" value="PAGO">Guardar datos</button> 
                          </form>
```

**Codio PHP encargado del guardado de datos**

```
require 'conexion.php';
 
 $idusuario= $_POST= session_id();
 $NTarjeta  = $_POST['labelNumero'];
 $CVV  = $_POST['labelcvv'];
 $NombreTarjeta = $_POST['labelnombre'];
 $FechaVencimiento  = $_POST['labelfecha'];
 $NumeroTelefono  = $_POST['labeltelefono'];
 

$insertar = "INSERT INTO datospago VALUES ('$idusuario','$NTarjeta','$CVV','$NombreTarjeta','$FechaVencimiento','$NumeroTelefono') ";                     

$query = mysqli_query($conectar, $insertar);

if($query){

   echo "<script> alert('Datos registrados');
    
   </script>";

}else{
    echo "<script> alert('Error favor de ');
  
    </script>";
}
```

Estos son los datos que se registran mi base de datos, como pueden ver son solo 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Agradeceré mucho cualquier ayuda o consejo para este estudiante novato, que tenga un buen día :D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para añadir valores a una tabla se usa:

`INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Además esto está mal: `$idusuario= $_POST= session_id();`
Sería: `$idusuario= session_id();` ya que la sesión sería la misma, y esa sesión no la mandas por el formulario.

Comment: hola buenas noches, muchas gracias me ayudaste muchísimo ahora ya guardo todos los valores, excepto el id si no fuera mucha molestia me podrías dar un consejo para poder agregarlo, otra vez muchas gracias :D

Comment: No sé a que te refieres pero puedes usar $_SESSION['lo_que_quieras_guardar']